# Difficultly with $locationChangeStart and $stateChangeStart events in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, authentication, angular-ui-router

I'm having the classic problem where the `$locationChangeStart` event fires multiple times. I've tried to use the `preventDefault` but I can't seem to master this.

Two problems - first scenario uses `$location` and the second uses `$state`:

1. Once user is authenticated, I redirect using `$state.go('main')` ,  however `$locationChangeStart` is fired again. I do not want this behavior.
2. With the ui-router `$stateChangeStart` event, I basically hit an `infinite loop` scenario. Meaning that, when this event fires I check for `user authentication`. If the user is NOT authenticated, I then redirect using `$state.go('login');`. This causes an infinite loop.

Here's my app.js for starters:

```js
(function () {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('rage', [
       'ui.router',
       'ui.bootstrap',
       'ui.dashboard',
       'kendo.directives'       
    ]).run(['$rootScope', '$state',  '$location', 'userService', 'loginService', init]);

    function init($rootScope, $state, $location, userService, loginService) {
        $rootScope.rageSessionVars = {};
        $rootScope.$state = $state;        
        $rootScope.isLoggedin = false;   // just something to possibly use ???


        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function () {

            var userToken = loginService.getUserCookie();

            // check if cookie expired, then authenticate user !
            if (userToken) {
                if (!loginService.isUserCookieExpired(userToken)) {
                    if (loginService.authUser(userToken)) {
                        $state.go('main');
                    }
                    else {                     
                        $location.url('index.html#/?login');    // not authenticated !
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                $state.go('login');
                $location.url('index.html#/?login');
            }
        });

    }

})();
```

I've also created a plunker for a similar scenario yesterday, and simply modified the `app.js` to now include the locationChangeStart event.

Online plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/hsSrPqFp0hpJ4A8cTsVL?p=preview

Bottom line is I'd like to hook into one of these event for a smooth user Login/Logout experience, but I always end up in a snag with these Angular events.

Thank you in advance for your expert tips.

regards,
Bob

Comment: Doing that in terms of route resolvers is always preferable http://stackoverflow.com/a/33021912/3731501

Answer (score 1):

While using angular ui router, use `$stateChangeStart` and `$stateChangeSuccess` to control actions like authentications and manual routing during state changing.

Comment: I was using `$stateChangeStart`, but I was running into a similar situation where it would fire multiple times. Perhaps I should revisit $stateChangeStart events

Comment: okay so I've updated my plunk to include `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart')` . I seem to be already in an indefinite loop. My goodness - http://plnkr.co/edit/hsSrPqFp0hpJ4A8cTsVL
            return token;
        };

Comment: I'm already familiar with the angular ui route events like `$stateChangeStart`, but as I mentioned before - I have difficulty implementing them. Please see my plunk, which has an endless loop in my `$stateChangeStart`. Note: In my app.js, I've added a `return;` statement to prevent the endless loop for now.