# Initialize AngularJs app before calling the controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have an AngularJs application in which I want to load the messages and application version at the very beginning and save them in local storage, then use them in the controllers afterwards. What I have for now is a service call in each of the controllers (which are three for now):

```
 localisationService.getMessages($scope.language).then(
            function (data) {
                $scope.messages = data;
                //initialze kendo grids with the messages etc.
                //all of the controller logic is here
 }
```

I want to take the application version only once and store it there. I don't have to check the version each time, right (In case a new message was added in the new version)?

I found a suggestion to use [$routeProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16288468/4355116) but my application is not a SPA. So I need other ideas/suggestions. Your help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your application is not an SPA why are you using angular? Infact, why aren't you rewriting it to be an SPA?

Comment: I'm planning to do that in some time, I just have to get this working for now.

Comment: If you change pages the browser will reload everything, that is how browsers work.

Comment: Perhaps you can do something with the Web Storage API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: I'm using localStorage and I want to make the http get for the messages and version before using the controller. Something like app bootsrapping

Comment: You miss the fact that in your case the language is dynamic. If you load the messages before app initialization, you're unable to change the language later, aren't you?

Comment: @estus my idea was to load the messages on initialization and then each time when the language changes. I also want to keep the messages version and also get the messages again when the app version is different than the local storage version

Comment: Then you likely want to go for a solution that is capable to handle both scenarios, i.e. router resolver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the question already mentions, this is usually solved with router resolvers because the initialization of route controllers can be naturally postponed this way. Since AngularJS router uses [hashbang mode by default](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location#hashbang-mode-default-mode-), it can be used with non-SPA (and can be recommended for complex non-SPA widgets):

```
resolve: { 
  l10n: (localisationService) => {
    return localisationService.getMessages(localisationService.language)
  }
}
```

The result can be optionally cached to avoid requests when `language` is unchanged.

Additionally, [route definitions can be processed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35928137/3731501) to add common local dependency (`l10n`) to all routes automatically.

The problem with global services that should be asynchronously initialized can also be solved in Angular 2 and higher with asynchronous bootstrapping and `APP_INITIALIZER` provider. AngularJS doesn't have this capability. As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41660722/3731501) explains, in order to implement this in AngularJS there should be two applications, where initializer application loads all necessary data and then bootstraps main application:

```
angular.module('app', [/* ... */]);

angular.module('appInitializer', [])
.factory('loader', ($http) => {
  return $http.get('...').then((result) => result.data);
})
.factory('initializer', (loader, $document) => {
  return loader.then((data) => {
    angular.module('app').constant('l10n', data);

    $document.ready(() => {
      angular.bootstrap($document.find('body'), ['app']);
    });
  });
});

angular.injector(['ng', 'appInitializer'])
.get('initializer')
.catch((err) => console.error(err));
```

Considering that in original code the language is defined dynamically with `$scope.language`, second option (initializer application) is not applicable, and this should be performed with first option (route resolvers).