# Run a function before running a controller

Tags: angularjs, promise, angularjs-service, angularjs-factory, angularjs-provider

I have defined a factory `auth` as follows:

```
app.factory('auth', [function () {
    var auth = {};

    auth.getUser = function () {
        ... ...
        // get user from cookie, cache, history, etc.
    }

    return auth
}]);
```

For many pages, I want to always run `auth.getUser()` before displaying them. To this end, at the moment, I use `resolve`, eg:

```
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: '/htmls/home.html',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    resolve: { getUser: ['auth', function (auth) { return auth.getUser() }]}
 })
```

The pitfall of this implementation is I have to write lots of `resolve`. Thus, I am wondering if there is a way to implement this rule in **controllers** rather than **state**. Could anyone help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Initialize AngularJs app before calling the controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391797/initialize-angularjs-app-before-calling-the-controllers)

Comment: As for specifying a resolver automatically for all routes, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33813535/3731501

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the condition in

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {
  //condition here and $state.go('')
});
```

I'm not sure if this works.

Answer (score 0):

```js
use angular run function
app.run(function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

see http://jsfiddle.net/ysq3m/