# Inserting service in ES6 class filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I want to use `$http` service inside my filter. Now I get the following error

```
angular.js:12477 TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined
    at factory (next-schedule-occurrence.filter.js:32)
...
```

How can I inject `$http` correctly?

HTML Template:

```
<p>Next execution: {{watcher._source.trigger.schedule.later | nextScheduleOccurrence}}</p>
```

Filter code:

```
/* global angular */
import moment from 'moment';
import later from 'later';

/*
* Get the next occurence of from the 'later' lib text schedule
*/
class NextScheduleOccurrence {

  /*
  * @param {string} schedule in English for the 'later' text parser
  */
  constructor(schedule) {
    this.schedule = schedule;
  }

  /*
  * @return {string} the future occurrence for the schedule
  */
  next(config) {
    if (config.es.watcher.schedule_timezone === 'local') {
      later.date.localTime();
    }
    return moment(later.schedule(later.parse.text(this.schedule)).next()).format('D/M/YYYY H:m:s');
  }

  /*
  * @param {string} schedule in English for the 'later' text parser
  */
  static factory(schedule, $http) {
    const filter = new NextScheduleOccurrence(schedule);
    return $http.get('../api/sentinl/config').then((config) => {
      return filter.next(config);
    });
  }
}

NextScheduleOccurrence.factory.$inject = ['schedule', '$http'];
export default angular.module('nextScheduleOccurrence', [])
.filter('nextScheduleOccurrence', () => NextScheduleOccurrence.factory);
```

---

UPDATE

I get the same error if I use a function for the filter instead of the class.

```
const NextScheduleOccurrence = function (schedule, $http) {
  return $http.get('../api/config').then((config) => {
    if (config.es.watcher.schedule_timezone === 'local') {
      later.date.localTime();
    }   
    return moment(later.schedule(later.parse.text(schedule)).next()).format('D/M/YYYY H:m:s');
  }); 
};

NextScheduleOccurrence.$inject = ['schedule', '$http'];
export default angular.module('nextScheduleOccurrence', []).filter('nextScheduleOccurrence', () => NextScheduleOccurrence);
```

Comment: (1) `constructor(schedule, $http) { this.$http = $http; ...` (2) use `this.$http.get(...)`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey I get the same error

Comment: you don't need to pass it as a parameter into the function itself, it's a public variable within a class, just use `this.$http` once you declare it in your constructor

Comment: DI went wrong there. Considering that NextScheduleOccurrence is factory function, it should be `.filter('nextScheduleOccurrence', NextScheduleOccurrence)`. And NextScheduleOccurrence  should return a filter function, not class instance. It's unclear how the thing is supposed to work in your case, because A1 wasn't designed for async filters. You likely have XY problem, because `config` shouldn't be loaded like that. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47391797/initialize-angularjs-app-before-calling-the-controllers/47394275#47394275 for some ideas.

Comment: Do you know, that filter function runs extremely often? Do you really want to send dozen of http requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your factory method should return a function like this

```
static factory($http) {
  return function(schedule) {
    const filter = new NextScheduleOccurrence(schedule);
    return $http.get('../api/sentinl/config').then((config) => {
      return filter.next(config);
    });
  }
}
```